# How to design countdown with Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtimer

The code below creates a single `QLabel` and starts a countdown. Every second it prints a current time and how many seconds left.

[image]

Aside from printing the current time (Time now) I would like to print what time it is going to be when the count down reached the end. So the resulting message would look like this:

```
"Time now: 20:00:01. Countdown ends at: 20:00:16"
```

How to achieve it?

```
import datetime
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

label = QtGui.QLabel()
label.resize(360, 40)
label.show()

count = 15
def countdown():
    global count 
    if count < 1:
        count = 15
    label.setText( 'Time now: %s. Seconds left: %s'%(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"), count))
    count = count - 1

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(countdown)
timer.start(1000)

app.exec_()
```

## Working solution:

(thanks to eyllanesc):

[image]

```
import datetime
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

label = QtGui.QLabel()
label.resize(360, 40)
label.show()

count = 15
def countdown():
    global count 
    if count < 1:
        count = 15
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    label.setText( 'Time now: %s. End time: %s. Seconds left: %s'%(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), (now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=count)).strftime("%H:%M:%S"), count))
    count = count - 1

interval = 1200
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(countdown)
timer.start(1000)

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have `datetime.timedelta()` added to the "remaining time":

```
 ...
 now = datetime.datetime.now()
 end = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=count)
 label.setText('Time now: %s. Countdown ends at: %s' % (now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), end.strftime("%H:%M:%S")))
 ...
```

[image]

Comment: It's nice to see answers that fit in my browser window. All that scrolling makes me tired :)